# Контракт Share в UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как реализовать кнопку "Поделиться" в UWP проекте?

Comment: посмотрите [тут](http://peterfoot.net/2015/08/20/add-sharing-to-your-uwp-app/)

Answer (score 4):

Курите статью [Add Sharing to your UWP App](http://peterfoot.net/2015/08/20/add-sharing-to-your-uwp-app/). По минимуму:

1. Добавить кнопку:

   ```
   <Page.TopAppBar>
     <CommandBar>
       <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
         <AppBarButton Label="Share" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
           <AppBarButton.Icon>
             <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="& #xE72D;"/>
           </AppBarButton.Icon>
         </AppBarButton>
       </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
     </CommandBar>
   </Page.TopAppBar>
   ```
2. Добавить в обработчик нажатия вызов `ShowShareUI`:

   ```
   private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
   }
   ```
3. Добавить обработку запроса на расшариваемые данные:

   ```
   Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView()
      .DataRequested += MainPage_DataRequested;

   void MainPage_DataRequested(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataRequestedEventArgs args)
   {
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentText.Text))
      {
         args.Request.Data.SetText(ContentText.Text);
         args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.DisplayName;
      }
      else
      {
         args.Request.FailWithDisplayText("Nothing to share");
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: ну и прикольная фича: без подписки на событие вызов метода ShowShareUI ничего не даст.